# Using gVim with Visual Studio 2010; where to create visualstudioinvoke.vim?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vim

Looking to set up gVim as an external tool for Visual Studio 2010, following: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio but I ran into some trouble. I'm on Window7x64 and I'm not sure where to put the `visualstudioinvoke.vim` file it mentions when it says to `set autoread`.

I've put it in `C:/Vim` and `C:/Vim/vimfiles` but still, when I change the file in VS10 and go back to gVim, it prompts me to load or continue editing.

While I can just set autoload every time, I'd also like to customize more feature, like syntax highlighting etc, but I'd need to store it in this file, I think.

**edit**: Just ended up changing my `_vimrc` to `set autoread`. Hopefully this won't bit me in the ass at some point. Still looking for a better solution though.

Comment: Why do you want to create a separate `vimfiles` directory? If you don't need it then don't. Just put that file to `E:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles`.

Comment: @xaizek You mean the `visualstudioinvoke.vim`? I'll try it out. edit: just put it there, and No effect.

Comment: Yes, don't complicate it unless you're going to maintain your Vim's configuration in a custom directory (e.g. in `d:/home/vimfiles` if you set `%HOME%` to point to `d:/home`).

Comment: Because Windows uses `%USERPROFILE%` instead of `%HOME%`. You can see `$HOME` in Vim or programs that you run from it, since Vim defines it on startup. As I said if you define `%HOME%` manually in advanced system settings Vim will use it (you will also need to move your `_vimrc` to that directory in this case).

Comment: @xaizek you mean in the Computer > advances system settings > environment variable then? I'll manually set it to `%HOME%` = `E:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles`, then move `_vimrc` somewhere else too. Wouldn't this affect all other files that rely on `%HOME%` too? Git etc. Why wouldn't putting the `visualstudioinvoke.vim` in the same directory as `_vimrc` work?

Comment: Yes, there, but use `HOME` (without percent signs). Yes, it will affect where Git will look for global `.gitconfig` file. It won't work placed near `_vimrc` because that directory isn't in `'runtimepath'`. And that's why I suggested putting `visualstudioinvoke.vim` to `E:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles` as an easiest solution, which should work. Did you try it?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased the question poorly, I meant that I had tried putting the invoke file in the folder without any success and I was asking why that wouldn't be working either. I'm wary of changing `HOME` though, but if that's the only solution left, I don't have much choice.

Comment: It's not the only one. You can also replace `:runtime` command and relative path with `:source` and full path to your script in command in Tools Settings of Visual Studio.

Comment: That sounds a bit more efficient. In the command box, I've got copied from the wiki: `--servername VimStudio --remote-silent +"call cursor($(CurLine),$(CurCol))" $(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt)` do I append `:source e:/program files/vim/vimfiles/invoke` and that's that?

Comment: Yes, appending `+"source e:/program files/vim/vimfiles/visualstudioinvoke.vim"` should work.

Comment: This is now my command: `--servername VimStudio --remote-silent +"call cursor($(CurLine),$(CurCol))" $(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt) +"source E:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\visualstudioinvoke.vim" ` and it's still not working. The contents of the file is only `set autoread` nothing else. edit: even tried changing the backslashes to forward slashes in the file path.

Comment: I forgot about space, you need to escape it with a slash (one should be enough, not sure since I can't check the exact command on Linux).

Comment: `t +"call cursor($(CurLine),$(CurCol))" $(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt) +"source E:/Program Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vimfiles/visualstudioinvoke.vim"` did not work, even after I took off the extraneous slashes around the `(` and `)`. Tried moving `visualstudioinvoke.vim` to `c:` and used the path `"C:\visualstudioinvoke.vim"` and that didn't work either: `--servername VimStudio --remote-silent +"call cursor($(CurLine),$(CurCol))" $(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt) +"source C:\visualstudioinvoke.vim"`

Comment: Try to move plus sign inside double quotes and/or change order of options. I'm sure it should work. There is probably some very small thing that we're missing. And try running this command from command line (replacing all VS vars manually).

Comment: @xaizek Son of a bitch! Just moved the source before the first`--remote-silent` arg and it worked. `--servername VimStudio --remote-silent +"source C:/visualstudioinvoke.vim" +"call cursor($(CurLine),$(CurCol))" $(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt) ` It's strange that the cursor command still works, as in it wasn't disabled after being placed second, like the `invoke` one was. Now write an answer up so I can shower you with reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following that tutorial word by word isn't necessary. You can also replace `:runtime` command and relative path with `:source` and full path to your script in command in Tools Settings of Visual Studio.

So adding to command something like

```
+"source c:/path/to/visualstudioinvoke.vim"
```

instead of

```
+"runtime visualstudioinvoke.vim"
```

should do the trick.

**Note:** after reading documentation it turned out that all `+cmd` should go before any file names for `--remote-silent`. From `:help --remote-silent`:

```
--remote-silent [+{cmd}] {file} ...
```

So be sure to place all `+cmd` before file name, otherwice Vim will treat them as file names.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in `%HOME%`. Your _*vimrc* should already be here if you're using one. In the windows explorer, type `%HOME%`. In windows7 this should be `c:\Users\username`; in XP: `c:\Documents and Settings\username`.

In this directory create a folder named `vimfiles` if it doesn't already exist. Put *vimfiles.vim* in the top level of that directory.

Then, in gvim, edit the file with: `:e $HOME\vimfiles\visualstudioinvoke.vim`, and add:

```
set autoread
```

Save the file, and try it out.

Comment: Strange. `%HOME%` wasn't found in WE. Went to `c:/users/usr` and added `vimfiles` folder, added `vimfiles.vim` in it, along with `visualstudioinvoke.vim`. Still not enabled. Also, shouldn't it be `:e filepath`?

Comment: Do `:set runtimepath?` in gvim. Do you see a home directory _vimfiles_ there? Note the question-mark

Comment: Yeah first one: `~/vimfiles`, along with a few others. Tried adding a `.vim` folder in the users folder, and no luck with that either. **edit**: still yeah

Comment: `runtimepath=~/vimfiles,E:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,E:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73,E:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,~/vimfiles/after` if you're curious